# Plot alignment and formatting help in Matplotlib and Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have a dataframe with 15 rows, which I plot using a seaborn heatmap. I have three plots, each with different scale for the heatmap. The first two plots are the first two rows, which are not aligned on the plot.

I have created a grid with 15 rows, I give each of the first two rows 1/15th of the grid so I don't know why it is not aligned.
Another problem with the first two rows of the heatmap is that the text formatting doesn't work either.
So I want to do two things:

1. Stretch the top two rows of the table to align it with the bottom one and;
2. To make the formatting work for the top two rows as well.
3. Maybe also add titles to my white xaxes (l1 and l2) that separate the the subgroups in the bottom plot (standard methods like ax.set_title does not work).

My code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gs

gs = gs.GridSpec(15, 1) # nrows, ncols
f = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 15))
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(220, 10, as_cmap=True)

ax1 = f.add_subplot(gs[0:1, :])
ax2 = f.add_subplot(gs[1:2, :])
ax3 = f.add_subplot(gs[2:15, :])

ticksx = plt.xticks(fontsize = 18, fontweight='bold')
ticksy = plt.yticks(fontsize = 18, fontweight='bold')

wageplot = sns.heatmap(df[0:1], vmin=3000, vmax=10000, annot=False, square=True, cmap=cmap, ax=ax1, yticklabels=True, cbar=False, xticklabels=False)

tenureplot = sns.heatmap(df[1:2], vmin=45, vmax=100, annot=True, square=True, cmap=cmap, ax=ax2, yticklabels=True, cbar=False, xticklabels=False)

heatmap = sns.heatmap(df[2:15], vmin=0, vmax=1, annot=False, square=True, cmap=cmap, ax=ax3, yticklabels=True, cbar=True, xticklabels=True)

heatmap.set_xticklabels(cols, rotation=45, ha='right')

l1 = plt.axhline(y=1, linewidth=14, color='w', label='Female')
l2 = plt.axhline(y=5, linewidth=14, color='w', label='Education')

f.tight_layout()
```

I would appreciate if I can pointed to where can I get some information about how to program the needed grid. An example image:

[image]

Comment: and here's a preview http://postimg.org/image/if6itunph/

Comment: I've added your image inline to the post, please make sure the edits are as you intended.

Comment: I suspect that it will be easier to lay things out exactly as you want them if you create the Axes where you want the colorbar to go and pass it to the `cbar_ax` parameter of `heatmat`.

Comment: @mwaskom bear in mind that I need to scale the colors differently for rows:1,2, and 3-15, so it means I need three different scales for coloring, so I created three separate heatmaps that I want to align n a gridline with the ratio: 1,1,13. I have also tried with height_ratios[1, 1, 13] and I don't even know if it works with three values and I get an error: IndexError: index 6 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 6